# Comparing values in loop inside function

Tags: f#, inline, c#-to-f#

I want to make a function that takes an integer list as argument and compares every value and returns the largest value. In C# I would simply iterate through every value in the list, save the largest to a variable and return it, I'm hoping F# works similarly but the syntax is kinda iffy for me, here's what my code looks like. Also max2 is a function that compares 2 values and returns the largest.

```
let max_list list = 
    let a = 0 : int
    match list with
    | head :: tail -> (for i in list do a = max2 i a) a
    | [] -> failwith "sry";;
```

Comment: I assume you don't want to simply call [`List.max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee370242.aspx), right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `mutable` variable and write the code using `for` loop, just like in C#. However, if you're doing this to learn F# and functional concepts, then it's good idea to use recursion.

In this case, recursive function is a bit longer, but it demonstrates the key concepts including pattern matching - so learning the tricks is something that will be useful when writing more complicated F# code.

The key idea is to write a function that takes the largest value found so far and calls itself recursively until it reaches the end of the list.

```
let max_list list = 
  // Inner recursive function that takes the largest value found so far
  // and a list to be processed (if it is empty, it returns 'maxSoFar')
  let rec loop maxSoFar list = 
    match list with
    // If the head value is greater than what we found so far, use it as new greater
    | head::tail when head > maxSoFar -> loop head tail
    // If the head is smaller, use the previous maxSoFar value
    | _::tail -> loop maxSoFar tail
    // At the end, just return the largest value found so far
    | [] -> maxSoFar
  // Start with head as the greatest and tail as the rest to be processed
  // (fails for empty list - but you could match here to give better error)
  loop (List.head list) (List.tail list)
```

As a final note, this will be slow because it uses generic comparison (via an interface). You can make the function faster using `let inline max_list list = (...)`. That way, the code will use native comparison instruction when used with primitive types like `int` (this is really a special case - the problem only really happens with generic comparison)

Comment: Always heard F# involved ALOT of recursion, thanks for this example very useful.

Comment: In practice, you do not need recursion *that* often, because you can mostly compose existing function - in this case, you could just use `List.max` and in most cases, there are some existing functions. But it is nice to know recursion if you need something that is not there already.

Answer (score 3):

Also know that you can write a nice one-liner using reduce:

```
let max_list list = List.reduce (fun max x -> if x > max then x else max)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to be able to find the maximum value of items in a list where the value of the items is found by the function max2 then this approach works:

```
let findMax list =
   list 
   |> List.map (fun i -> i, max2 i)  
   |> List.maxBy snd
   |> fst
```